# Best practice : Remove table row with d3.js or css

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a complex script which handles a few functions , i am trying to make my scripts and browser load time as fast as i can. I am removing row based on business requirement , however i would like to know what are the best approach and practise . Both of the method i have provided below are both working script

1. Is to remove table row using d3.js
   script are as follow

   ```
   const table_id = d3.select("#" + arcapi.chartId() + ' .dataTables_scrollBody table').attr('id') 
   var getRow = d3.selectAll("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " .dataTables_scrollBody tbody tr :nth-child(" + (colIndex) + ")")

      getRow.filter(function(){
        const cf_percent = d3.select(this).text();
        const cf_regex = cf_percent.replace(/[`~%]/gi, '');
        if(parseInt(cf_percent) === 65){
           const index = d3.select(this).node().parentNode.rowIndex;
           document.getElementById(table_id).deleteRow(index)
        }
      })
   ```
2. Second method is by setting the class added to display:none  hide / set display to none to selected

   ```
   var getRow = d3.selectAll("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " .dataTables_scrollBody tbody tr :nth-child(" + (colIndex) + ")")
      getRow.filter(function(){
        const cf_percent = d3.select(this).text();
        const cf_regex = cf_percent.replace(/[`~%]/gi, '');
        if(parseInt(cf_percent) === 0){
          d3.select(this).node().parentNode.attr('class','removerow')        
        }
      })
   ```

in the given example , which method should i go on with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, changes to the DOM (adding/removing elements) are more expensive than hiding elements. However, if values are not going to change often, a cleaner DOM would be easier to navigate (`document.getElementById`, `d3.select`).

I would recommend using the CSS approach, but I would clean it up in the following way:

```js
d3.selectAll("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " .dataTables_scrollBody tbody tr")
  .classed('removerow', function() {
    const cf_percent = this.children[colIndex].innerText;
    const cf_regex = cf_percent.replace(/[`~%]/gi, '');
    return parseInt(cf_percent) === 0;
  });
```